# Use underscores instead of dashes with ActiveResource XML (set :dasherize to false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I am hitting all kinds of walls trying to stop rails from replacing XML underscores with dashes. I'm doing a post to a web service using ActiveResource. I have tried all kinds of variations of fixes for this, with results varying from rails initialization errors to just no effect. The web service I am posting to requires underscores.

Essentially, if I can get the following in place, I should be good:

From http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveResource/Base

```
:dasherize - Boolean option to determine whether or not element names should replace underscores with dashes. Default is true. The default can be set to false by setting the module attribute ActiveSupport.dasherize_xml = false in an initializer.
```

Can someone provide an example of this? I'm unfortunately on a tight timeline, so if someone can provide assistance that would be a huge help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Did you attempt to set the module attribute to false in an initializer?

```
ActiveSupport.dasherize_xml = false
```

for rails 3+ you can use the following within your response:

```
render :xml => object.to_xml(:dasherize => false)
```

See edit history for ugly monkeypatching approach.

Comment: I attempted, but had various errors including ActiveSupport not having that property. If someone can give me a proper example of an initializer setting that property that would get me what I need. Right now I am just overriding to_xml in each ActiveResource model

Comment: check the updated answer to see if it is of any use.  You can also extend your own subclass of ActiveResource to make this even cleaner.

Comment: +1. two comments: 1) AFAIK `render :xml => object.to_xml(:dasherize => false)` should work in Rails 2. 2) Why show hacking solution (last 2 snippets) when the other two ways you show work? Don't encourage unnecessary monkeypatching.

Comment: @tokland the edit history shows just what you suggest; I agree, monkeypatching is nearly always a sin.  In the spirit of a more current answer, I'm removing the ugly.  Thanks!